# AWS S3: Host override cannot be combined with Dualstack, FIPS, or S3 Accelerate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I setup AWS S3 acceleration in one of my buckets, mybioinformaticsm and use S3 acceleration to upload a big file from local to S3, as in a following command;

```
aws s3 cp /Volumes/Documents/R/BM/bm.int s3://myawsbioinfo/bm.int  --region us-east-2 --endpoint-url https://myawsbioinfo.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com
```

It used to work until recently.  When I use this command, it failed with a following error message;

```
Host override cannot be combined with Dualstack, FIPS, or S3 Accelerate
```

I have not set up Dualstak and am not sure about FIPS.  At this point, I would really appreciate any input on this.

Comment: This might be due to updates in the S3 sdk.  I am hitting the same error via the aws js and php sdk after many months of stable use and then doing a new release with fresh packages.  Unable to determine exactly where the update has occurred yet.

Comment: I've tried almost every remedies I could think of but none has worked. I thought this might have some to do with an issue with S3 region but I am still struggling to determine what is the reall issue.     I posted the same question in AWS re:Post a while agobut I have not gotten any response yet.  This makes me think the issue may be isolated cases or S3 acceleration is not as popular.

Comment: I managed to get around the issue in the PHP SDK specifically by specifically setting config options for `use_dual_stack_endpoint` and `use_fips_endpoint` to false.  In looking at the docs it would appear these are false by default but I suspect some other bug in aws is setting them to true.

For CLI try  `aws configure set default.s3.use_dualstack_endpoint false` and `aws configure set default.s3.use_fips_endpoint false`

Comment: To further clarify..  I had to actually revert to version of aws-php-sdk from early november (v 3.242.1)  to work around the issue as subsequent updates appear to ignore config settings for `use_dual_stack_endpoint` and `use_fips_endpoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use S3 accelerate, I would suggest to *not* use the `--endpoint-url` argument. Instead, set the `s3.use_accelerate_endpoint` configuration to `true`. You can do this either with the command `aws configure set default.s3.use_accelerate_endpoint true` as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transfer-acceleration-examples.html) or by editing the [config file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) directly. The CLI will then determine the correct endpoint to use. Based on the error message you report, you may already have the `s3.use_accelerate_endpoint` setting enabled.

Some additional context and a method for debugging which setting is causing the error message:

The AWS CLI v2 updated its logic for endpoint resolution in [version 2.9.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/releases/tag/2.9.0) which was released on November 18, 2022. AWS CLI v1 received the same update earlier in version [1.26.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/releases/tag/1.26.0) on October 24, 2022. Endpoint resolution is the process by which the correct hostname for a given service and operation is determined based on inputs such as the region name and configuration settings. The new versions use endpoint ruleset files that are shared between AWS SDKs in different languages. For example, the S3 endpoint ruleset file is [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/endpoint-rule-set-1.json). The error `Host override cannot be combined with Dualstack, FIPS, or S3 Accelerate` is defined in this file.

For low level debugging purposes, it is possible to see what parameters the endpoint ruleset was invoked with by adding [the `--debug` flag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-troubleshooting.html#general-debug) to the command:

```
aws s3 cp /foo/bar s3://mybucketname/object.txt --region us-east-2 --endpoint-url https://mybucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com
```

When run on a system with default configuration settings, the debug output contains these two lines:

```
Calling endpoint provider with parameters: {'Bucket': 'mybucketname', 'Region': 'us-east-2', 'UseFIPS': False, 'UseDualStack': False, 'Endpoint': 'https://mybucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com', 'ForcePathStyle': True, 'Accelerate': False, 'UseGlobalEndpoint': False, 'DisableMultiRegionAccessPoints': False, 'UseArnRegion': True}
Endpoint provider result: https://mybucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com
```

Note that `'UseFIPS': False`, `'UseDualStack': False`, and `'Accelerate': False` and that an endpoint is returned and not an error. The reported error appears if one of these parameters is not `False`. The ruleset contains this error condition because, in the general case, it is impossible to know whether the value of `--endpoint-url` should take precedence over the S3 transfer acceleration setting, or vice versa. Of course, in this specific case the outcome would be the same.

Enabling the S3 transfer acceleration setting and dropping the `--endpoint-url` argument results in these lines:

```
Calling endpoint provider with parameters: {'Bucket': 'mybucketname', 'Region': 'us-east-1', 'UseFIPS': False, 'UseDualStack': False, 'ForcePathStyle': False, 'Accelerate': True, 'UseGlobalEndpoint': False, 'DisableMultiRegionAccessPoints': False, 'UseArnRegion': True}
Endpoint provider result: https://mybucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com
```

Note that this is the correct endpoint for using S3 transfer acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing your bucket name from `--endpoint-url` and try just the following.

`aws s3 cp /Volumes/Documents/R/BM/bm.int s3://myawsbioinfo/bm.int  --region us-east-2 --endpoint-url https://s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com`

AWS is likely (wrongly) determining your endpoint as a custom endpoint.  It seems the direction of the various sdk's is to dynamically determine endpoints based on profiles and options.  Another option would be to turn accelerate on by default and do not include the `--endpoint-url` at all.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transfer-acceleration-examples.html